# clip rectangle from pdf file with absolute coordinates

Tags: graphics

Below code can clip pdf to a smaller one:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[trim=0 9800 0 0,clip,clip=true]{1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

for this case I need to know 9800 unit to bottom will be removed.

What I want is to keep absolution coordinate, e.g. keep rectangel at (0,0) to  (400,300). How can I do such clip?

coordinates start from top to bottom and left to right!

Comment: `[viewport=0 0 400 600,clip]`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just try viewport but it point to middle of pdf file, not exactly top,left as origin.

Comment: `\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 400 300, clip]{1.pdf}` works for me. Or do you intend "total height-400", "total width-300"?